# Run a php script on localhost using cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job on my localhost to call a `php` script every half an hour 24/7. Following are my steps:

1) I have created a cron.php file to call `myscript.php`:

```
<?php

echo exec('*/30 * * * * C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\php -f C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\myscript.php');

?>
```

2) Created a cron.bat file to run the `cron.php` on browser:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "localhost\cron.php"
```

3) Then I have set up a windows 7 task scheduler to call `cron.bat` every day.

I welcome any idea on how to set up a cron job as my approach doesn't do anything.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to run firefox for that? Rewrite your script to run in console instead of webserver context. You just need the batch script containing the `php.exe .../myscript.php` from your exec() line (without the invalid */30 * * cron specifier).

Comment: Thanks, I have created a .bat file to call three scripts and set up a windows task scheduler to run them every half an hour and it works fine. Except that the scripts are running in sequence, I want the scripts to run in parallel.Any suggestions?                           task.bat:                                                        php.exe C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\myscript_1.php
php.exe C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\myscript_2.php
php.exe C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\apache2\htdocs\myscript_3.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but only pointers you need to check before you proceed further.

1. Crons are available only on unix systems, not windows.
2. While debugging cron or anything similar, schedule them for every minute or (any such acceptable smaller frequency), and once they work every minute, only then schedule them for the original frequencies. That will save you some time during debugging.
3. Its an incorrect call to [exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec). You don't have to pass all those `*` in it
4. Since this is windows, You want to do `php.exe` and not `C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.21-0\php -f` which would have been done in linux (with proper path)
5. Your `.bat` file is currently scheduled daily, you need to schedule it every half hour.

Answer (score 0):

dude, you cannot define cron jobs in wamp, 
the cron is a linux feature and you are running the wamp on windows.

you can run the script from the command line (of from cygwin, much better),
something like "/php.exe "
but you cannot define crons on wamp

but you can setup the scheduler to run a .bat file that contains the next code
cd/
cd "Program Files (x86)"
cd GnuWin32
cd bin
wget.exe http:// localhost/... (your file)
echo DONE

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to creat .bat file to run php script

follow the step to setup cron job for php interpreter..

step 1- Then I have set up a windows 7 task scheduler to call php script by giving path of php interpreter like C:\xampp\php\php.exe  filename.php  by setting desired interval